# Python passing in a list of parameters to be used as dynamic properties

Tags: python, list, parameter-passing, args

I have this which is specific to Jinja2 templating within Flask(but is not specifically related to either, is just the context I'm working in to construct something more general):

```
class MultipleMacroFor(object):
    def __init__(self, macro):
        self.macro = macro

    def renderable(self, macro_var):
        return get_template_attribute(self.macro, macro_var)

class ResponseItemMacros(MultipleMacroFor):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ResponseItemMacros, self).__init__(macro="macros/response_items.html")

    @property
    def general_macro(self):
        return self.renderable('general_macro')

RI = ResponseItemMacros()
```

An example for a use case:

```
 RI.general_macro # returns the renderable 'general_macro' from 'macros/response_items.html' that can be used with in a Jinja2 template
```

Which I want to turn into this:

```
class MultipleMacroFor(object):
    def __init__(self, macro, which_macros):
          self.macro = macro
          self.which_macros = which_macros

     # take which_macros and have them each be returnable as in the function above but
     # respond to the more general case, not specifically requiring construction  
     # @property
     # def (passed in var which_macro)(self):
     #   return self.renderable(passed in var which_macro)

RI = MultipleMacroFor(macro="macros/response_items.html", macros=['general', 'etc', 'etal'])
```

then use case:

```
RI.general_macro #as above but without having to construct the intermediate ResponseItemsMacros class
```

and have the list passed in be called as a property, only dynamically contructed based on the passed in list and not manually constructed as the first example. The first example requires manually constructing from two classes the instance I want to use. The second is the wish use just 1 class that can be instanced with properties to be called, which would work through the renderable function to produce the relevant named macro.

Only I don't know exactly how to do this atm. Any input appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question nor the relation between the example and the question. Could you expplain more clearly what do you want, maybe giving some code that uses the `MultipleMacroFor`?

Comment: fair enough, clarifications added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have per-instance properties (or at least not without messing with **get_attribute**, which is something you really should avoid). The simplest solution is to use **getattr**.

```
class MultipleMacroFor(object):
    def __init__(self, macro, names):
        self._macro = macro
        self._names = names

    def get_renderable(self, macro_var):
        return get_template_attribute(self.macro, macro_var)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._names:
            return self.get_renderable(name)
        raise AttributeError(
            "object %s has no attribute '%s'" % (
                type(self).__name__, name)
            )
```

A more involved way is to dynamically build a subclass then instanciate it.

```
class MultipleMacroFor(object):
    def __init__(self, macro, names):
        self._macro = macro
        self._names = names


    def get_renderable(self, macro_var):
        return get_template_attribute(self.macro, macro_var)

def MultipleMacroForFactory(macro, names):
    attrs = dict()
    for name in names:
        attrs[name] = property(
            lambda self, name=name: self.get_renderable(name)
            )

    clsname = "MultipleMacroFor%s" % "".join(
        name.capitalize() for name in names
        )

    return type(clsname, (MultipleMacroFor,), attrs)(macro, names)
```

Comment: The second seems more involved than I'm looking for atm, but the first is what I was looking for but didn't quite understand how to go about it when originally asked, so let me try that

Comment: I don't understand why you mention `__getattr__` and the write a class with `__getitem__`.

Comment: @blueblank: the nice point with the second solution is that the properties are visible thru introspection. As an added bonus descriptors come first in the name lookup rules while `__getattr__` is the last resort after every other possible resolution has been tried, but this is really micro-optimzing <g>.